# What does $O(d^2)$ mean in dimension of vector $2d+{d \choose 2}\approx O(d^2)$?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I understand that it means that the dimension is roughly of order $d^2$. Is that the correct interpretation?

Thanks

Comment: Cf. [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation); it means there is a positive number $M$ and a number $D$ such that, for all $d\ge D$, $|2d+\binom d2|\le Md^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cf. [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation); it means there is a positive number $M$ and a number $D$ such that,

for all $d\ge D$, $$\left\vert 2d+\binom d2\right\vert\le Md^2.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is big-O notation. It means that there is $K$ such that $2d + \binom{d}{2} \le K d^2$ for all sufficiently large $d$.

Since $\binom{d}{2} = \frac{1}{2}d(d-1) = \frac{1}{2}d^2-\frac{1}{2}d$, in fact any $K > \frac{1}{2}$ will witness this fact.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.